# Multisite on Rackspace Cloud (ubuntu lucid)

Tags: multisite, customization, server

First post in this astonishing exchange. Glad to be here.

I've installed WP3 on Rackspace Cloud, under an Ubuntu Lucid installation, properly configured all the multisite dependancies, network blogs are being successfully created, data is stored in the database, which leads me to one conclusion regarding my failure in actually USING network blogs, and that that it's somehow connected to Apache configuration.

I admit I'm still slow on my Apache, but I'm getting there. Any leads you can share with me?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, can you give more details about the issue you have? I gave an answer to your question, assuming the wildcard domain was not setup on your server. Let me know if that help. And if the problem is elsewhere, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if your install meets the requirements: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#WordPress_Settings_Requirements.

E.g.: you will not be able to use subdomains if your url is an ip address

Comment: Thanks. In case the domain is still an IP address, just use that?

Comment: ok, I edited my answer.